# problem with a beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I like a lot the beamer theme "Air" (you can find it by the link "Nice Air based template for Latex" at the page http://www.kde.org/kdeslides/ ). But sometimes, in a slide, my text is a little too long, and if I could withdraw the air-header.png on the top, it could be nice. So, can you help me please? In fact, I think that the best idea is to modify the `beamerthemeAir.sty`, with the part:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \pgfuseimage{air-header}
  \vskip -1.95cm
  \linethickness{0.0pt}

  \framelatex{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.3\beamer@headheight]{Title bar}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0pt}{\hskip0.22cm}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}

  \framelatex{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.7\beamer@headheight]{Title bar}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
}
```

becoming optional, for example, it could appear only when the slide has a title whith a `\frametitle`. If you don't know, please say it to me, I will delete this part from the `sty` file.

Comment: You can use `shrink` or `plain` option for the  frames with large content. Look at beamer documentation...

Comment: @Ludovic Can you please tell me from where you have downloaded the Air package theme? I'm not getting that from your given KDE site.

Answer (score 7):

As **Paul Gaborit** mentions in his comment, you can use the `plain` option for those frames (to effectively remove the headline and footline) or you can use the `shrink` option (this option will cause the text of the frame to be shrunk if it is too large to fit on the frame).

In the following example I show the same contents (taken from `example-talk.tex`) in three different frames with three settings; first, the default behaviour showing the blocks protruding; the second one shows the effect of the plain option, and the third one shows the effect of using the *evil* option `shrink`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Air}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Prerequisites \& Goals}
  \framesubtitle{Knowledge is a brick wall that you raise line by line forever}
  \begin{block}{LaTeX}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Obviously some basic LaTeX knowledge is necessary
    \item Some more features will be provided here
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Beamer}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item You'll learn them by looking at this presentation source
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Beamer}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item You'll learn them by looking at this presentation source
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Goal}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Learn how to make well structured slides
    \item Using a beautiful theme (congrats to the Oxygen team!)
    \item Take over the world
    \item Relax...
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \frametitle{Prerequisites \& Goals}
  \framesubtitle{Knowledge is a brick wall that you raise line by line forever}
  \begin{block}{LaTeX}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Obviously some basic LaTeX knowledge is necessary
    \item Some more features will be provided here
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Beamer}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item You'll learn them by looking at this presentation source
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Beamer}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item You'll learn them by looking at this presentation source
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Goal}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Learn how to make well structured slides
    \item Using a beautiful theme (congrats to the Oxygen team!)
    \item Take over the world
    \item Relax...
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[shrink=10]
  \frametitle{Prerequisites \& Goals}
  \framesubtitle{Knowledge is a brick wall that you raise line by line forever}
  \begin{block}{LaTeX}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Obviously some basic LaTeX knowledge is necessary
    \item Some more features will be provided here
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Beamer}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item You'll learn them by looking at this presentation source
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Beamer}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item You'll learn them by looking at this presentation source
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Goal}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Learn how to make well structured slides
    \item Using a beautiful theme (congrats to the Oxygen team!)
    \item Take over the world
    \item Relax...
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As a personal opinion, frames with too much text should be avoided (if possible); the best option is to distribute the material in such a way that it fits on the frame without any special treatment.